# Having trouble with stringing multiple functions together

Tags: python, string

basically I am writing a function that uses the previous 2 that takes as an input parameter 2 numbers `x`, the number of times you want to play and `y`, the upper limit on the guess. The loop keeps track of how many times you win... but whenever I run it the total is always 0 and I cannot figure out where I have gone wrong here is the code. (`so_fun` is where the trouble starts) although it may be a problem in the previous functions that is messing up the lower function...

```
def closer(x,y,z):
    if (abs(x-y))<(abs(x-z)):
        return (True)
    else:
        return (False)


print(closer(4,2,7))

def grumpy(x):
    goal_num=randrange(0,x)
    user_guess=int(input('guess a number between 0 and ' + str(x)))
    comp_guess=randrange(0,user_guess)
    print(closer(goal_num,user_guess,comp_guess))

def so_fun(x,y):
    total=0
    while x>0:
        if grumpy(y):
            total+=1
        x -=1
    print(total)
```

Comment: `grumpy` does not return anything. Change the print to return

Comment: I assume you mean to `return` instead of `print` in the `grumpy` function? Also, refrain from using `()` around returns unless you specifically want to return a tuple.

Comment: You should give your variables and functions meaningful names. `grumpy` means nothing to anyone reading your code, and this is a site all about having people read your code.

Comment: sorry, I will keep this in mind next time I am going to put in comments soon I am just too tired to do so now with the #

Answer (score 2):

the problem lies here:

```
if grumpy(y):
```

i dont think the function grumpy returns anything. So, this condition is evaluated as false always and the if block is never executed. Try returning some value from grumpy function.

Comment: changing that print to return helped everything thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason is that you not return value from 'grumpy' while checking it in if statement. Check this:

```
from random import randrange

def closer(x, y, z):
    return abs(x-y) < abs(x-z)

def grumpy(end):
    goal_num = randrange(0, end)
    user_guess = int(raw_input('guess a number between 0 and {0}'.format(end)))
    comp_guess = randrange(0, user_guess)
    return closer(goal_num, user_guess, comp_guess)

def so_fun(x, y):
    total = 0
    while x > 0:
        if grumpy(y):
            total += 1
        x -= 1
    print total

so_fun(7,5)
```

Comment: `True if abs(x-y) < abs(x-z) else False` is simply `abs(x-y) < abs(x-z)`, no?

Comment: @DSM ))) sure, edited, thanx, looks like i need to sleep more

Comment: Thanks, I need to sleep more too I appreciate your help... a lot of the syntax you are using we didn't learn yet in our class but I appreciate the help anyways.

Comment: @IanBerke you are welcome, you always can ask if you have any doubts on code